# How do I preserve all the original image data in a JPG in Android?

Tags: android, jpeg

I'm working with a client whose color style guides are completely immutable, and as part of their app there is a feature where JPGs that they provided are sent to the server.

I'm currently converting the images to bytestream and uploading thusly, but the images arrive with their colors slightly different than the original.

Here's my code for the byte stream creation...

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), uploadImgId);
b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);            
byte[] bitmapdata = stream.toByteArray();
```

I'm using 100% compression, so, I'm not sure why it's altering the image in any way.

Would it be more reliable to move the JPGs to the device's file system and simply upload a file?
Alternatively, would it be more reliable to use PNGs instead of JPGs? (I'm guessing PNG treats color information differently than JPG does).

TIA

Comment: Dredel: If you have the images at compile time, why are you wasting the user's time, battery, and bandwidth in uploading them? And doing so for every user? Just copy the files at compile time to the server once and be done with it.

Comment: do you need to do the decode/re-encode at all? Can you just send the original JPEG to the server?

Comment: @CommonsWare, because the images need to named something user specific in each instance.   @Jimmy, Is there way to avoid decode/re-encode? I need to upload the original with an alternate filename.

Comment: Dredel: "because the images need to named something user specific in each instance" -- then send a command to the Web server to say "yo, dawg, copy the stock image named Foo to a user specific value named Bar, yo". You do not need to upload images the server has already.

Comment: @CommonsWare, I appreciate the reasons for why the server should come prepared with the stock images, but that's not a solution for this application.  I think going with the PNG approach will be fine, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The executive summary is that you seem to be taking a bitmap and compressing it using JPEG. JPEG is lossy. If colours must be kept exactly right, you need a lossless codec, such as PNG.

The long story is as follows:

JPEG is a lossy codec. It compresses pictures by loosing information in the pictures that most humans will not notice.

This actually can occur in two stages:

A very common, although not mandatory step before JPEG compression is chroma downsampling. As the name implies, this involves loosing certain color information that humans are not usually sensitive to.

In addition, the DCT transformation, which is the next and mandatory step in JPEG, works by eliminating from the picture fine details that humans wont normally notice. This can, in certain pictures (such as with sharp edges) to cause further color changes.

PNG on the other hand is a lossless codec - it works by eliminating redundancy in the information in the image, but never loosing information. It is comprised from RLE followed by Lempel Ziv encoding, which are totally reversible.

In short, use PNG and save the original colors but beware that the pictures will be bigger so uploading time will be longer and cellular data bill might bigger as well.

Comment: Excellent. The info is being transferred on a closed network via WiFi, so the data transfer time is minimal and the file sizes won't affect any data charges. Thanks very much for the info.

Comment: How would I go about skipping the Bitmaping and just treating the Resource as raw data, read into a byte [] for sending? I'm assuming that would avoid messing with the colors, right?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel Sorry, JAVA is not one of my main expertise :-)

Answer (score 1):

.JPG & JPEG (Joint Photographic experts Group) compression is a lossy compression mechanism. This means that while the file you uncompressed may look like the original, most likely, if you do a binary compare on the file, you will find lots of differences  [Wikipedia lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). .JPG (and I think .PNG) files are both based on a discreet cosign transform (A subset of a Fourier transform) and part of the compression throws away any imagery square roots (usually occurs what you hit a sharp boundary/like a straight line in an image), so some information is always lost. The only way to store an image without loss would be to save the raw image as a bit map, or maybe use some of the old run-length encoding schemes that existed before the .JPG days, but don't expect much in the way of compression, maybe 50% reduction at best case.

Msg back if you need a better explination, but it will get very long winded - Joe